# Foreach on 2 variables in csh

Tags: foreach, csh

Is it possible in csh to do foreach on 2 variables like tcl ?

```
set test = (a 1 b 2)
foreach a b ($test) then
    echo $a
    echo $b 
endif
```

this code retrun an error

Comment: the error is your answer. No `tcl` improvements in `csh`.  Sorry (-;! If you really need to pair data in a `for` loop, I guess I would make the data "paired" and then split it inside (very ugly), i.e. `a:1 b:2`  . Hmm, very painful to use `awk` to split that, but I don't recall `csh` having anything that could split data expect `expr : ...(something)`.. Remind us again, why are you using `csh`?  Don't waste your career on a tool that has you work with one arm tied behind your back. ( If you really need this, I may have time later to figure some sort of splitter based on `expr`. ) Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot go away from csh on this one, and I agree csh is very limited if i could decide it's already been done in tcl :) I'll also try on my side to find a not so complicated answer to that

Comment: assuming your code above is a minimal representation of your prroblem, what is the real source of your paired list (`a:1,b:2`), and what are you feeding them into?